# jQuery click(function()) does not use variable on first click

Tags: jquery, variables, click

I have this tiny script:

```
var $totalHeight;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $totalHeight = $('#sidebar-container').innerHeight();
    $('.sidebar-heading').each(function() {
        $totalHeight = ($totalHeight - $(this).outerHeight());
    });

    $('.sidebar-contents').each(function() { 
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).css('height',$totalHeight);
        }
    });

    $('.sidebar-heading').click(function() {
        $('.sidebar-contents').slideUp().removeClass('active').addClass('inactive')/*.css('height','').removeAttr('style')*/;
        $('.sidebar-heading').removeClass('active')/*.next().slideUp()*/;
        $(this).addClass('active').next().addClass('active').removeClass('inactive').css('height',$totalHeight).slideDown();
    });
});
```

I am pretty sure it's obvious what it is supposed to do.

My problem is: The first click on a `('.sidebar-heading')` does not apply the desired `$totalHeight` to its sibling. The following clicks, it does. What am I doing wrong?

I have [a draft-HTML with this code in action](http://blog-n.de/wordpress-testsite/wp-content/themes/applike/dev-sidebar.html). I commented out those parts above to check, where the bug is, but couldn't figure it out anyway.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me. Maybe you **do** need to be a little more explicit in what you expect it to do and what it is actually doing.

Comment: Check out this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/z62tr/) .. the first click doesn't expand the full height.. but every other one does

Comment: the content-area should always be at full height. "Inactive" heading elements are supposed to either be at top or at bottom. not in between. With the first click, the following heading-elements are somewhere in the middle, not at the bottom of the container.

Comment: Any reason to name an integer variable `$totalHeight`? This is not PHP

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this behavior using Chrome (v24). What browser are you seeing this behavior in?

Comment: no, no need to use $ in variable, was just another try to debug. @JanDvorak
I am using Chrome 24.0.1312.52 or Firefox, which both show this behaviour

Comment: @pete I can reproduce this using Chrome v26. Please try refresh a jsfiddle page and click on the heading_1 as the first thing you do.

Comment: @runTarm i also happens when you click any other heading > 0

Comment: @RobertSteinhöfel What I mean is don't click the Heading_0 first!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also let the fx function set the height by itself to avoid conflict mentioned in @LeeMeador's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14405192/867480).

Since the **slideDown()** doesn't accept any css value, we can use the **animate()** function directly instead.

```
$('.sidebar-heading').click(function () {
    $('.sidebar-heading').removeClass('active');
    $('.sidebar-contents').removeClass('active').addClass('inactive').stop().animate({ height: '0px' });
    $(this).addClass('active').next().addClass('active').removeClass('inactive').stop().animate({ height: $totalHeight + 'px' });
});
```

In addition, use **stop()** before perform any animation to prevent weird behavior if you click the heading again while the previous animation haven't finished.

Modified jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z62tr/4/

Comment: I also thought about an approach using **animate()**. Thanks for this solution. On the first glance, it works for me :-)

Answer (score 3):

The slideUp() animation takes a while to run and cleans up all the heights and display styles after it gets done. This erases the setting you made in the next two lines.

Try waiting until slideUp() is done to do the other ones.

```
   $('.sidebar-heading').click(function() {
        var self = this;
        $('.sidebar-contents').slideUp(undefined, function() {
            $('.sidebar-heading').removeClass('active')/*.next().slideUp()*/;
            $(self).addClass('active')
                .next().addClass('active').removeClass('inactive')
                .css('height',$totalHeight).slideDown();
        }).removeClass('active').addClass('inactive')
        /*.css('height','').removeAttr('style')*/;
    });
```

I figured this out by running in Chrome with the debugger and noticing that the styles were changing in a wierd way. The first click on the 2nd heading would leave the height set on the 1st heading even though the code was clearing it. That means something was, maybe, setting it wrong. So I tried the above code on the jsFiddle someone set up. Lo and behold ...

Comment: Probably copied something wrong from the fiddle. Too many lines copied. Ill fix it.

Comment: I guess I was just confused by the lack of indentation. FTFY.

Comment: Can you provide the fixed fiddle? I would like to see your fix live.

Comment: Oh. The _first_ animation was removing the height. I was trying to catch the _second_ one red-handed.

Comment: [Fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z62tr/2/) showing the code change and thanks @JanDvorak for the reformatting.

Comment: Your fix still performs some weird animation, but at least the cause is now known.

Comment: Try [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z62tr/3/) and see if you like the animation better. I replaced the first animation, `slideUp()`, with `css("display", "none")`.

Comment: It's worse now. The strange bounce is fixed, but the jump looks much worse.